# Model state not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

So I have a view called index that lays out all of the threads in my database. Then inside that view I'm loading all the comments on the threads. When I call on my form that is supposed to create a new comment it keeps telling me that my model state is invalid. It tells me that it cannot convert from type string to type profile or comment or tag. Originally I had this as my code:

```
 public ActionResult AddComment(Thread thread, string commentBody)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _repository.AddComment(thread, comment);
            TempData["Message"] = "Your comment was added.";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Then I changed it to this:

```
 public ActionResult AddComment(Thread thread, string commentBody)
    {
        Profile profile = _profileRepository.Profiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id ==       thread.ProfileId);
        Tag tag = _tagRepository.Tags.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == thread.TagId);
        thread.ThreadTag = tag;
        thread.Profile = profile;
        Comment comment = new Comment()
                              {
                                  CommentBody = commentBody,
                                  ParentThread = thread
                              };
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _repository.AddComment(thread, comment);
            TempData["Message"] = "Your comment was added.";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

This still tells me that my model state is invalid. How do I get it so that it will not try to change the state?

Also here is the form that is being used to call this action:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "Thread", mod))
            {
                <input type="text" name="AddComment" id="text" />
                <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
            }
```

In the instance of code above mod is the model which is a thread.
And as requested here is everything inside of thread:

```
 public Thread()
    {
        this.ChildComments = new HashSet<Comment>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TopicHeader { get; set; }
    public string TopicBody { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UpVotes { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DownVotes { get; set; }
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> ChildComments { get; set; }
    public virtual Tag ThreadTag { get; set; }
```

And finally the comment class:

```
 public partial class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CommentBody { get; set; }
    public int UpVotes { get; set; }
    public int DownVotes { get; set; }

    public virtual Thread ParentThread { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you need to show what the `Thread` object looks like.

Comment: So I tried to remove the modelstate check and see if that worked. Now i get this error: "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."

Comment: well now your talking about Entity Framework. You need to provide more info. What does `_repository.AddComment(thread, comment)` do? Seems like all you should need to do is fetch the existing thread by it's ThreadId, then do `thread.Comments.Add(newComment);` then save the thread. that should be it.

Comment: public void AddComment(Thread thread, Comment comment)
        {
            
            _repo.SaveComment(comment);
            SaveThread(thread);
        }
That is the code for the add comment. Save comment is another repository that checks to see if the comment exists in the database and if not it creates it. if it does it just updates the existing one.

Comment: Also wouldn't I have to create a new comment and ad it to my db so that it is stored there? Plus updating the thread in the db?

Comment: RPM1984 you were right. Thank you.

Answer (score 61):

Use the code below to iterate through the errors. Then you can see what field and what object is failing on validation. And then you can go from there. Just looking at the IsValid property is not going to give enough information.

```
var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
```

And then loop through the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Before checking your error, you need to know why is the model state invalid. You can easily do that by debugging and seeing the list of errors.

The second error should be a separate questions as I believe to be written in stackoverflow guidelines.